# Explain the three types of Shudras?

Tags: shudra

According to birth based varna system
There are three types of shudras,
We are requesting to give clear explanation about three types of shudras

Comment: May I know, which śāstra mentions that Śūdras are of three types? You didn't provide any source in support of that claim. Also, varṇa does depend on janma, alongwith karma and saṁskāra. That varṇa doesn't depend on janma at all, is based on colonial & post-colonial mainstream nonsense. The tradition doesn't uphold that nonsense.

Comment: Hey @Bingming can u plz throw some light on what you said. I want to gather some resources so that I can get a clear idea about how varna is based on Birth and Samskaras and Karma all 3. What is the *actual varna of an individual? And the priority of the 3 types in order..

Comment: @LSSJBroly The smṛtis explain this pretty well. You may check Manusmṛti, Yājñavalkya smṛti, Parāśara smṛti, etc.

Comment: In certain areas like Bengal & Nepal, shudras are classified into 3 groups, the upper tier consisted of communities like kayasthas & vaidyas who had much social respect, the middle tier from whom water could be accepted by brahmins & the lower tier from whom water could be accepted by all but brahmins. Antyajas were considered even lower than the 3rd tier of shudras. In Nepal it was legal for upper castes like brahmins, chhetris & Rajputs to enslave the antyajas & the shudras from whom water can't be accepted.

Comment: Thank u @Bingming